# PrimeFaces onAdd listener for fileupload not invoking

Tags: primefaces, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to display the each file in alert box before i implements my own logic as per my requirements. But its not working.

```
<h:head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayEachFile(file,callback){
        alert(file);
    }
</script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="card">
    <h:form name="download">
            <p:fileUpload value="#{fileBean.files}" mode="advanced" multiple="true" auto="true"
            listener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}" widgetVar="hello" onAdd="displayEachFile"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: primefaces 10.0.0

Comment: It could be a bug already fixed are you getting errors in your console?  See this issue which was fixed for PF 11.0.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7364

Comment: Thanks, i went through the thread. May be that one is a seperate issue. Even much simple reproducer as  @jasper mentioned was simply place onAdd="console.log(this)" which blocks uploading files

Comment: Well was seeing if you could try it or use the PF Test reproducer in that ticket to try and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation Updated: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/fileupload

`onAdd` has 3 params `this, file, callback`.

Running example:
[pf-8657.zip](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/files/8457084/pf-8657.zip)

This gives you the opportunity to inspect the `file` and if you decide its OK to add you call `callback`.

For example:

```js
onAdd="onAddFile(file, callback);"
```

You could do something like only add files named `primefaces.pdf` for example.

```js
function onAddFile(file, callback) {
   if (file.name === 'primefaces.pdf') {
       callback.call(this, file);
   }
}
```